# Display something in every 3 seconds

Tags: c, linux

I can't figure out how to display something (like hello world) in every 3 seconds.
I'm writing in only C programming with gcc compiler in linux.
We can stop it by Ctrl+c.
I just want simplest and easiest way to manipulate thet code with my project.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may run into a problem in that standard output is normally buffered, which means that the implementation batches up output until it's convenient to write it.  If you're writing out every three seconds (and `sleep(3)` is a good way to do that), and it's not showing up every three seconds, try putting in `fflush(stdout);` or writing to the standard error output with `fprintf(stderr, "something\n");.

Comment: You save me. fflush(stdout) must be used to show every changes.

Answer (score 9):

```
while(1) {
    printf("something\n");
    Sleep(3000); //this function counts in milliseconds, so this is what 3 seconds looks like.
}
```

Comment: I just got blinking cursor. Nothing shows up! What should I do?

Comment: @Devyn, wait three seconds.

Comment: Well I actually waited more than 10 seconds. Here is my complete code.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  while(1) {
  printf("something\n");
  sleep(3);
  }
}

Comment: Works for me.  Try adding `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf()`?

Answer (score 4):

```
sleep(3);
```

The `sleep` function causes your program to wait X seconds before returning.  Note that this is between executions, so it won't be running your command exactly every 3 seconds, but close enough for most purposes.  Also, some platforms have `usleep` where the u stands for micro which could get you more resolution.  See the man pages for more information.

Comment: thanks for the reply. do we need any special header for that?

Answer (score 1):

The generic approach is to write an infinite loop (`while (1) { ... }`) and pause your program execution each tick.

To pause, you may use `sleep` function from standard library.  Alternatively to `sleep`, which can only specify sleeping time in seconds, you can use `nanosleep` function that allows better precision.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  struct timespec t = { 3/*seconds*/, 0/*nanoseconds*/};
  while (1){
    printf("Wait three seconds and...\n");
    nanosleep(&t,NULL);
    fflush(stdout); //see below
  }
}
```

Note that unless you add a newline character (`\n`) to the string you outpu, you most likely will see nothing, because the string is first printed to a buffer and that buffer is occasionally *flushed* to the terminal (that usually happens when you print a newline, but even this cannot guarantee the flush on every system).  That's why it's better to add `fflush` call.

Answer (score 1):

Only distantly related, but a technique I use all the time is to write a program to display something *once* then repeat it every *n* seconds by using [`/usr/bin/watch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch).  I get a lot more reuse that way.

Answer (score 0):

Stream's buffer type can be controlled using **setvbuf()** function. By default, streams referring to files are block buffered and terinals are line buffered (stdout) or unbuffered (stderr).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    while ( 1 ) {
        printf("Wait 3 seconds... ");
        sleep(3);
    }
}
```

Note that there's no **\n** in printf. If you comment out the **setvbuf()** call you can see how all the output come at once after filling the buffer (usually 1024 bytes).